# Best method to use latest version of celery on IIS production sever

Tags: python, windows, celery

I have implemented a flask application with celery for background task processing using redis as a message queue. On the development server I am able to send an asynchronous request and continue the background process on celery. I have read that the latest version of celery isn’t compatible with windows. How can I make it run on Microsoft IIS(internet information services) for production?

If not, what are the best alternatives for background processing/task queues available which would work on the IIS production server?

Answer (score 1):

It is really simple - run Celery workers on Linux boxes.

Comment: That’s not an option for us right now. Is there any other way to do it? Or can you recommend any other task queues which would work with IIS?

Comment: Task queues should have nothing to do with IIS, they are completely independent services. What you want is one which works on Windows it seems. Do not mix Flask and Celery together, they are separate things. Flask can run on Windows/IIS, while Celery can run on Linux, to offload stuff.